# How to pass @RequestBody parameter of controller using MockMVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

Parameters with @RequestParam annotation can be passed by using : post("/******/***").param("variable", "value")

but how can I pass value of parameter having @RequestBody annotation?

My test method is :

```
@Test
    public void testCreateCloudCredential() throws Exception {

        CloudCredentialsBean cloudCredentialsBean = new CloudCredentialsBean();
        cloudCredentialsBean.setCloudType("cloudstack");
        cloudCredentialsBean.setEndPoint("cloudstackendPoint");
        cloudCredentialsBean.setUserName("cloudstackuserName");
        cloudCredentialsBean.setPassword("cloudstackpassword");
        cloudCredentialsBean.setProviderCredential("cloudstackproviderCredential");
        cloudCredentialsBean.setProviderIdentity("cloudstackproviderIdentity");
        cloudCredentialsBean.setProviderName("cloudstackproviderName");
        cloudCredentialsBean.setTenantId(78);
        cloudCredentialsBean.setCredentialId(98);

        StatusBean statusBean = new StatusBean();
        statusBean.setCode(200);
        statusBean.setStatus(Constants.SUCCESS);
        statusBean.setMessage("Credential Created Successfully");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(cloudCredentialsBean);
        ArgumentCaptor<String> getArgumentCaptor =
            ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<Integer> getInteger = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);

        ArgumentCaptor<CloudCredentialsBean> getArgumentCaptorCredential =
            ArgumentCaptor.forClass(CloudCredentialsBean.class);
        when(
            userManagementHelper.createCloudCredential(getInteger.capture(),
                    getArgumentCaptorCredential.capture())).thenReturn(
            new ResponseEntity<StatusBean>(statusBean, new HttpHeaders(),
                HttpStatus.OK));

        mockMvc.perform(
            post("/usermgmt/createCloudCredential").param("username", "aricloud_admin").contentType(
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json)).andExpect(
            status().isOk());

    }
```

Controller method that is being tested is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createCloudCredential", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<StatusBean> createCloudCredential(
            @RequestParam("userId") int userId,
         @RequestBody CloudCredentialsBean credential) {            
            return userManagementHepler.createCloudCredential(userId, credential);
        }
```

Error that I am getting is :
[image]
How can I pass a mock value for **credential** here?

Comment: sorry I didn't get what are you suggesting

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand the question, but if you are asking how to pass the `@RequestBody` in the mock, you have your solution in your example: `mockkMvc.perform(
            post("/usermgmt/createCloudCredential").param("username", "aricloud_admin").contentType(
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json))`. You have converted it to json before: `String json = gson.toJson(cloudCredentialsBean);` and passed the content with `content(json)`. Is this what you want?

Comment: @PauChorro  but this is not working

Comment: Maybe you are passing as parameter `userName` but your `RequestParam` `isuserId` ? -> Try to put `/usermgmt/createCloudCredential?userId=aricloud_admin` instead of `.param("username", "aricloud_admin")`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `POST` request normally passes its `param` in its body. So I cannot understand what you expect by giving both a `param` and a `content` for same request.

So here, you can simply do:

```
    mockMvc.perform(
        post("/usermgmt/createCloudCredential").contentType(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json)).andExpect(
        status().isOk());
```

If you need to pass the parameter `"username=aricloud_admin"`, add it to the `JSON` string, or alternatively, pass it explicitly as a query string:

```
    mockMvc.perform(
        post("/usermgmt/createCloudCredential?username=aricloud_admin")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: I got the mistake, i have to pass "userId" inplace of "username" in param()